# How to make concentric circles in GMT

Tags: linux

I want to make this kind of concentric circles like [image: figure].

So, I use these commands:

```
pscoast -R0/360/0/90 -Js45/22/2/-60 -B -Dc -G200 -W1/0 -P > 1.ps

grdmath -Rd -I1 45 22 SDIST 111.13 MUL = dist.grd

grdcontour dist.grd -Glz-/z+ -S8 -C2000 -O -J -Wathin,red -Wcthinnest,red,- >> 1.ps
```

But the space between the circles seems not equal, like [image: figure].

Comment: Please format your question properly with code highlighted. As it stands its not readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem!

```
pscoast -Rd -JE45/22/100/4.5i -B30 -Fi -Ggray -W1/black -A1000 -K -P > 1.ps
grdmath -Rg -I1 45 22 SDIST = dist.grd
grdcontour dist.grd -A30 -L0/90 -C10 -O -J -Wathin,red -Wcthinnest,red,- >> 1.ps
```